# Readfile works on one image but not the next

Tags: php, file-get-contents, jpeg, readfile

I've got the code below to display images over https, but for whatever reason it works on a majority of images but the odd one doesn't..

The code is as below

```
<?php

//This one works
//$file = "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDEwWDY0MA==/$%28KGrHqJ,!pQFBWf4uEThBQkO-TbjYw~~60_12.JPG";

//This one doesnt
$file = "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDgwWDY0MA==/$T2eC16JHJIYE9qUcNbMwBQroE+MgEQ~~60_1.JPG";

ob_clean();
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo readfile($file);
```

As you can see it's a basic script, the first file (the one currently commented out) will work fine but the second one won't both files exist and appear to be near identicle

Comment: Try replacing double quotes with single ones to avoid $variable interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Use single `'` quotes and you also don't need `echo` when using `readfile`

```
$file = 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDgwWDY0MA==/$T2eC16JHJIYE9qUcNbMwBQroE+MgEQ~~60_1.JPG';

ob_clean();
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
readfile($file);
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ACghVN)